# Need to click on input button twice to submit the form (and POST)

Tags: html, forms

I have a very simple form to POST a couple of fields back to server. Problem is, I need to click the input button twice. On debugging on the server side, I found the first line in request is null when I click in first instance. In the second click, the request is proper, and so it goes as expected. This happens only once, GET the html, try to save the form the first time -> does not work, second click -> works, subsequently and until I refresh the page -> works fine with single clicks (and data changed)

Can you please help getting things right with a single click?

I have tried this on Google Chrome.

Here is the plain html, with no client side scripts at all. This is the only div tag in the html. There is no head tag.

```
<div>
  <form method="POST" action="/POSTrequest">
    Title:<br/>
    <input type="text" name="title" style="width:100%"/>

    <br/>Text:<br/>
    <textarea style="width:100%" name="text"></textarea>

    <br/>
    <br />
    <input type="submit" value="save"/>

  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Is this is exactly what you have in the page? Nothing else?

Comment: you dont have anything else like validation or javascript function call??

Comment: @Tieson T, Nothing else, of course the html and body tags, with no attributes.

Comment: @mjsoft, no javascript validations. In fact there are no script references on this page.

Comment: "of course the html and body tags" - unfortunately, the "of course" part isn't a given on Stack Overflow, so that question does need to be asked, since that's relevant to the question and possible answers.

Comment: @Tieson T, Apologies.

Comment: @HarshChiki No apology required. Sorry if that came across that way.

Comment: I hope you do not have form inside a form. A nested form.

Comment: @rach8garg, No, I do not have a form inside a form.

Comment: did not find a solution yet ? @HarshChiki

Comment: Not yet. Just looking around for that tiny little miss.

Answer (score 0):

Everything seems fine with the following change in the html.

```
<form method="post" action="/POSTrequest" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    ... (same as in the question)
</form>
```

Ensuring the response to the POST request has a header 'Connection:keep-alive' and not closing the sockets (instances of Socket(Java) on the server side)

Answer (score -1):

You can add the id attribute in your form element and Try this in Javascript:

```
<input type="button" value="save" ondblclick="save()">

<script> function save(){document.getElementById('myForm').submit()} </script>
```

Comment: Thanks for posting. But why would I need specific/forceful handling, when the native behaviour is to generate a proper POST request on click of the input. This could may be used as a work around.